# How to order (two columns) long text inside one div with pure css?

Tags: html, css

I have one div with a lot of title and paragraphs. I need to make them look nice.
Two columns -> like in a table Title 1 (with all paragraphs) is left, Title 2 is right etc.
The problem is I CANNOT change html at all.

```css
.container {
  font-size:10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Title1</h2> 
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h2>Title2</h2> 
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h2>Title3</h2> 
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h2>Title4</h2> 
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I've tried to use h2:nth-child(odd) ... but somehow it does not work for me. Don't know why ...

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is right?

Comment: <h2> are not closed with </h2>. Probably you should wrap title and relative p into div container

Comment: thanks for comment, I change it here ... but in my code is everything right

Comment: Use css grid or columns

Comment: @TemaniAfif how exactly?

Comment: @Vova https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-a1x32v?file=styles.css You need to play with CSS Grid.